# send requests from AWS lambda to IOT device and wait response

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, aws-lambda, aws-iot

I have created a alexa smart home skill. I am currently sending request to my raspberry pi from the AWS lambda for the skill using MQTT. Then the response is generated by the lambda regardless to any logic running on the pi or if it even runs at all. I would like to send a response for the lambda function to return from the pi.

I can invoke a lambda function with MQTT or the API gateway but this is no use as it need to be access able to the instance to the function invoked by alexa to return the response.

I could do this using HTTP but I would have to expose a port to my pi. I don't have enough knowledge about security issue to be comfortable doing this.

Is there a way to achieve this with MQTT, web sockets or any other secure method?

Answer (score 0):

so you what to send a request to IoT device using mqtt from AWS Lambda function.yes it is possible by creating a lambda function which will publish on a topic and iot device will received it

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

 var iotdata = new AWS.IotData({
 endpoint: 'akugdx70brb.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:8883',
 apiVersion: '2015-05-28'
});

     var params = {
  topic: 'terminal2/test/',
  payload: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE',
  qos:1
};
iotdata.publish(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});

};`
```

pls let me know is this way you have to implement. if not i will provide you another way